# how to refresh the tabcontrol in silverlight, i tried everything i can think of, but it is stubborn

Tags: c#, silverlight, tabcontrol

here are the codes, i would like that the tabcontrol allow the change in the datagrid to be displayed/but it doesnot work.

- note without this tabcontrol datagrid displayed the change on view/delete

### NOTE

- please study the tab "VIEW/DELETE DATA" when delete click, let the datagrid refresh.

### xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using SilverlightClient.ServiceReference1;

namespace SilverlightClient
{
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }


        private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //onsubmit button clicked
            //insert operation

            DemoServiceClient webService = new DemoServiceClient();

            webService.InsertDataCompleted += new EventHandler<System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs>(webService_InsertDataCompleted);

            webService.InsertDataAsync(TestItem1TxtBox.Text, TestItem2TxtBox.Text);


        }

        void webService_InsertDataCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();

            return;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //onget button clicked
            //select operation
            DemoServiceClient webService = new DemoServiceClient();


            webService.GetRowsCompleted += new EventHandler<GetRowsCompletedEventArgs>(webService_GetRowsCompleted);

         //results returned by this cannot be used directly
            //as the method works asynchronously thereby allowing
                //to proceed before the results are generated.
                    //there must do anything regarding results 
                         //using the completed event handler
            webService.GetRowsAsync();



        }

        void webService_GetRowsCompleted(object sender, GetRowsCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
           // ResultsGrid.ItemsSource = e.Result;

            ResultsGrid.ItemsSource = null;

            List<Table1> gamma= e.Result.ToList();

            ResultsGrid.ItemsSource = gamma;




            tabControl1.UpdateLayout();


           // tabControl1.TabIndex = 1;

        }

        private void OnDeleteClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //remove operation
                Table1 selectedRow = ResultsGrid.SelectedItem as Table1;

                        // Now access the service to delete the item
                    DemoServiceClient webService = new DemoServiceClient();
                    webService.DeleteRowAsync(selectedRow.KEY);

                    // Now refresh the grid
    webService.GetRowsCompleted += new EventHandler<GetRowsCompletedEventArgs>(webService_GetRowsCompleted);

    webService.GetRowsAsync();
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //UPDATE BUTTON

            //get the selected row
            Table1 selectedRow = ResultsGrid.SelectedItem as Table1;
            //declare the web service
            DemoServiceClient webService = new DemoServiceClient();
            //call the update method
                //do pass the GUID and the UPDATE text
            webService.UpdateDataAsync(selectedRow.KEY, textBox1.Text);

            //assign the event handler
            webService.GetRowsCompleted += new EventHandler<GetRowsCompletedEventArgs>(webService_GetRowsCompleted);
            //call get rows
            webService.GetRowsAsync();

        }





    }
}
```

### xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightClient.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="600" d:DesignWidth="600" xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" Height="600" Width="600">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="20*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="555*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="25*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="66*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="468*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="66*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <sdk:TabControl Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Height="555" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="tabControl1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="468" BorderThickness="0,2,0,0">
            <sdk:TabItem Header="Insert Data" Name="tabItem1" FontFamily="Trebuchet MS">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="328*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="128*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="65*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="74*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="22*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="122*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="235*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <sdk:Label Height="64" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="2,1,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="106" Content="TestItem1" Grid.Column="1" />
                    <TextBox Height="52" Margin="0,1,4,0" x:Name="TestItem1TxtBox" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    <sdk:Label Height="64" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="2,0,0,0" Name="label2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="106" Content="TestItem2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />
                    <TextBox Height="64" x:Name="TestItem2TxtBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,4,0" Grid.Row="1" />
                    <Button Content="Submit" Height="23" Name="button2" Width="133" Click="button2_Click" Margin="191,0,4,121" Grid.Row="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" />
                    <TextBox Grid.Row="3" Height="121" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="325" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Height="121" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="textBlock1" Text="Update Text for TEXT item 2, please select guig key by using the VIEW/DELETE DATA TAB" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="123" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                </Grid>
            </sdk:TabItem>
            <sdk:TabItem x:Name="TABview" Header="View/Delete Data">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="29*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="155*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="24*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="27*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="286*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <sdk:Label HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="label3" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="173" Content="Datagrid Silverlight" Margin="0,3,0,0" />
                    <sdk:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" Height="155" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="ResultsGrid" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="456"   Cursor="Hand"  GridLinesVisibility="All" Grid.Row="1" />
                    <Button Content="Get" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="135,2,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="149" Click="button1_Click" />
                    <Button Content="Delete" Height="26" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="381,0,0,0" Name="button3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="OnDeleteClick" />
                    <Button Content="Update" Grid.Row="3" Height="27" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="320,0,0,0" Name="button4" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="132" Click="button4_Click" />
                </Grid>
            </sdk:TabItem>
        </sdk:TabControl>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

### demoservice.svc.cs

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;


namespace WcfSqlDemoWeb
{
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class DemoService
    {


        // Return the list of valid data
        [OperationContract]
        public List<Table1> GetRows()
        {


            DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();


            var selected_rows = from rows in db.Table1s select rows;


            return selected_rows.ToList();

        }

        // Insert a new data into the database
        [OperationContract]
        public void InsertData(string testItem1,
                               string testItem2)
        {
            DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
            // Create a new row object.
            Table1 row = new Table1
            {
                KEY = Guid.NewGuid(),
                TestItem1 = testItem1,
                TestItem2 = testItem2
            };


            // Add the new object to the collection.
            db.Table1s.InsertOnSubmit(row);

            // Submit the change to the database.
            db.SubmitChanges();

            db.Dispose();

            return;

        }


        [OperationContract]
        public void UpdateData(Guid key, string update_text)
        {
            DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
            // get the row with the key as a single tuple
            var original_row = (from rows in db.Table1s where rows.KEY == key select rows).Single();
            // get the row with the key
            var delete_row = from rows in db.Table1s where rows.KEY == key select rows;

            //a new instance of the table
                //assiging it values as needed
           Table1 changed_table = new Table1
           {
               KEY = key,
               TestItem1 = original_row.TestItem1,
               TestItem2 = update_text
           };

            //delete the row completely with the original selected record
           db.Table1s.DeleteAllOnSubmit(delete_row);
            //now insert the newly created TABLE INSTANCE
           db.Table1s.InsertOnSubmit(changed_table);
            // Submit the change to the database.
            db.SubmitChanges();




        }//update data ends






        // Delete the item specified by the passed key
        [OperationContract]
        public void DeleteRow(Guid key)
        {

            DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();

            var selected_row = from rows in db.Table1s where rows.KEY == key select rows;

            // Delete the selected "rows". There will actual be only one
            // item in this collection because the Guid is unique and is the
            // primary key for the table.
            db.Table1s.DeleteAllOnSubmit(selected_row);

            // Submit the change to the database.
            db.SubmitChanges();
        }


        /*

        //here it will give a error message stating,
            //the sql return type is not serializable
            //please make a datacontract and then try.

        //so simply put, support for this type of data handling is being
            //removed

        // sql select all
        [OperationContract]
        public SqlDataReader sqlSELECT()
        {


            string connectionstring = @"Data Source=DEVELOPMENT-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=SILVERLIGHT;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False";

            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();

            connection.ConnectionString = connectionstring;

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();

            command.CommandText = "select * from Table1";

            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            command.Connection = connection;

            connection.Open();

            var results_by_sql = command.ExecuteReader();


            return results_by_sql;






        }


        */





        // Add more operations here and mark them with [OperationContract]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this... it is not an answer to your specific problem, but just a quick way to get it working in a way that could be considered "better". It uses binding with a notifying property to supply your grid with data. I've only included the relevant bits of code that you would need to change, you can fill in the rest.

```
namespace SilverlightClient
{
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.dataContext = this;
        }

        void webService_GetRowsCompleted(object sender, GetRowsCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            MyResults = e.Result.ToList();

            tabControl1.UpdateLayout();
        }

        protected List<Table1> MyResults
        {
            get { return _myResults; }
            set 
            {
                if (_myResults != value)
                {
                    _myResults = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("MyResults");
                }
            }
        }

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) 
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArg(propertyName));
        }

        private List<Table1> _myResults = null;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

```
<sdk:DataGrid Name="ResultsGrid" 
              ... etc ... 
              DataContext="MyResults"
              />
```